# Convert English latin number using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change all english/latin number in body to persian number. for this i have this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    persian = {
        0: '۰',
        1: '۱',
        2: '۲',
        3: '۳',
        4: '۴',
        5: '۵',
        6: '۶',
        7: '۷',
        8: '۸',
        9: '۹'
    };

    function traverse(el) {
        if (el.nodeType == 3) {
            var list = el.data.match(/[0-9]/g);
            if (list != null && list.length != 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
                el.data = el.data.replace(list[i], persian[list[i]]);
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < el.childNodes.length; i++) {
            traverse(el.childNodes[i]);
        }
    }
    traverse(document.body);


});
```

This worked for me but when i add [jQuery Countdown](http://www.littlewebthings.com/projects/countdown/example/js/jquery.lwtCountdown-0.9.5.js) my code not convert latin number to persian number.

How do can i fix this ?

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jLxsf1n4/)

Comment: You only do the traverse once so it doesn't affect the numbers being changed by countdown plugin. You would have to do the conversion each time the countdown does it's work. I believe it's bad solution because it will lack performance.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably not the best solution, but you can modify the plugin itself. The method `digitChangeTo()` can be modified to switch Persian characters instead:

```
$.fn.digitChangeTo = function (digit, n, duration) {
    if (!duration)
    {
        duration = 800;
    }
    if ($(digit + ' div.top').html() != n + '')
    {
        $(digit + ' div.top').css({'display': 'none'});
        $(digit + ' div.top').html(persian[n]).slideDown(duration);
        $(digit + ' div.bottom').animate({'height': ''}, duration, function(){
            $(digit + ' div.bottom').html($(digit + ' div.top').html());
            $(digit + ' div.bottom').css({'display': 'block', 'height': ''});
            $(digit + ' div.top').hide().slideUp(10);
        });
    }
};
```

Have in mind that you have to add your `persian` array to the plugin.

You normally shouldn't modify the plugin, but for performance purposes modifying the characters each second is worse solution.

Answer (score 0):

You really want jquery do this for you? 
Here's a javascript piece of code that can help you:

```
    var map = ["\u0660","\u0661","\u0662","\u0663","\u0664", "\u0665","\u0666","\u0667","\u0668","\u0669"];

    function replaceNumbers(node) {
        if (node.nodeType==3) //Text nodes only
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(/[0-9]/g, getArabicNumber);
    }

    function getArabicNumber(n) {
        return map[parseInt(n,10)];
    }

    function walk(node, func) {
        func(node);
        node = node.firstChild;
        while (node) {
            walk(node, func);
            node = node.nextSibling;
        }
    };

    walk(document.body, replaceNumbers);
```